# Inverse operation in a True Group with multiple identity elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a hypothetical algebraic set.  It is a True Group, a Monoid where the elements may be inversed (not necessarily an Abelian group).

$S$ is of infinite size but only three of its members concern us:  $a$ is a left identity element, $b$ is a right identity element, $c$ is a dual-identity element (both left and right identity).  For argument's sake, $a$ ≠ $b$ ≠ $c$ ≠ $a$

Does this mean $S$ has different inverse functions, one for each identity element?  Or can a True Group only have a single identity element?

Thanks in advance

(I'm only an armchair mathematician looking at the properties of algebraic operations so please be gentle! :)

Comment: A group (I have never seen anyone refer to a true group before) has a unique identity element, and each element has a unique inverse.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this without knowing the precise definition of "true group".

Comment: @ Derek Holt: a Monoid where the elements may be inversed (not necessarily an Abelian group).

Comment: That is just a group (since groups are not necessarily abelian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $S$ is of infinite size but only three of its members concern us:  $a$ is a left identity element, $b$ is a right identity element, $c$ is a dual-identity element (both left and right identity).  For argument's sake, $a$ ≠ $b$ ≠ $c$ ≠ $a$.

Then you immediately have a contradiction since $c=ac=a$, and $c=cb=b$, and so $a=b=c$.

They cannot all exist distinctly as (whatever flavor) of identities for a single binary operation.

The similar thing can be said for uniqueness of inverses. If $b'$ is a left inverse of $b$, and $b''$ is a right inverse, then $b'=b'(bb'')=(b'b)b''=b''$. So when a left and right inverse exist, they are equal, and thus two-sided.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification; I couldn't quite find it in my own research.